# Copy one jagged array ontop of another

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

How could I accomplish copying one jagged array to another?  For instance, I have a 5x7 array of:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

and a 4x3 array of:

```
0,1,1,0
1,1,1,1
0,1,1,0
```

I would like to be able to specify a specific start point such as (1,1) on my all zero array, and copy my second array ontop of it so I would have a result such as:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are your arrays always rectangular? If so, why not use a rectangular array instead of a jagged array?

Comment: An observation - the example arrays are both rectangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the squared nature of your example, this seems more fitting of a 2D array instead of jagged. But either way, you could certainly do it the old fashioned way and loop over it. Something like (untested)

```
for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < secondArray[0].Length; j++)
    {
        firstArray[startingRow + i][startingColumn + j] = secondArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Like Mark, I also had a slight improvement, slightly different but along the same lines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.Length; i++)
{
    secondArray[i].CopyTo(firstArray[startingRow + i], startingColumn);
}
```

Comment: +1: With your edit, your solution also works for non-rectangular arrays. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work even if your inputs are not rectangular:

```
void copy(int[][] source, int[][] destination, int startRow, int startCol)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
    {
        int[] row = source[i];
        Array.Copy(row, 0, destination[i + startRow], startCol, row.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good edit. I was about to add `secondArray[i].CopyTo(firstArray[startingRow + i], startingColumn);` instead of my inner loop. You beat me!

Comment: @Anthony: Actually CopyTo is very good here - you should make that change.